# simple_form radio buttons not aligning correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have the following code in my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for :phrase do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :phrase, label: 'Phrase you would like to add:' %>
      <%= f.input :emotion, collection: [[true, 'Positive'], [false, 'Negative']], as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Emotion', label_method: :last %>
      <%= f.input :category, collection: @categories, as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Categories', label_method: :last %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :comment_id, :value => @comment.id %>
      <%= f.button :submit, 'Add to Dictionary' %>
<% end %>
```

The issue is with the `f.input :emotion` and `f.input :category` lines. Both of these produce radio buttons, but in every instance the radio button is actually slightly above the text that follows. The form works correctly as far as submitting the choices, but the buttons aren't lining up with the text beside them.

Any suggestions on how to clean this up or get those buttons to align with their respective options?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `item_wrapper_class: 'inline'` to your `input`.

```
<%= f.input :emotion, collection: [[true, 'Positive'], [false, 'Negative']], as: :radio_buttons, label: 'Emotion', label_method: :last, item_wrapper_class: 'inline' %>
```

Comment: This aligns everything correctly, but causes the radio button/text pairs to bundle up horizontally. Is there a way to do this but still have my options run vertically up and down the page?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :emotion, [[true, 'Positive'], [false, 'Negative']], :first, :last, label: 'Emotion' %>
```